# Can you identify this flower?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I have found this plant in my garden. I watered it, and now it is blooming. I have no idea what plant it is. Could someone help me to identify this plant? My geographic location is the Indian subcontinent. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort to bring it up to flowering-stage.

Comment: +1 for making it flower. Would it be possivle to add a picture were we can see the flower more closely? See how many petals it has and maybe the color of the stamens inside.

Comment: I would say it's champa (plumeria) from the leaves but the flower hardly resembles it. Besides, plumeria's white species is more common in the indian subcontinent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but I think it is water leaf plant ( called sambar cheera ).If you see other pictures, the leaf and flower color matches but I am not sure as I do not know how the flower looks when it is bloomed ( in your picture).
You can see this site http://papanasini.blogspot.in/2012/02/cylon-spinach-sambar-cheera.html

I got a picture of the above-mentioned plant from my house, unfortunately, it is not having flowers and I will get back when it will have one.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Finally.. I think this is the one.. Thank you Sarannya E..